# ListGrid column auto fit layout

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

```java
ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();

listGrid.setWidth100();

listGrid.setFields(f1, f2);
vlayout.addMember(listGrid);

listGrid.setAutoFitFieldsFillViewport(false);
listGrid.setAutoFitFieldWidths(false);
listGrid.setCanAutoFitFields(false);

ListGridField[] listGridFields = listGrid.getFields();
for (ListGridField listGridField : listGridFields) {
  listGridField.setAutoFitWidth(true);
}
```

I've got this lines but when I resize the window in which I put listGrid, the fields do not resize and fit the new width.

Could someone help me to make the width of the fields of this listGrid fit the window ?

Then if I put this :

```java
ListGridField[] listGridFields = listGrid.getFields();
for (ListGridField listGridField : listGridFields) {
  listGridField.setWidth("100%");
}
```

It resolve the problem when I resize the window on first time. But resizing a field make a gap on the right between the last field and border of the listGrid.

Is there a way to solve this ?

**Summary :**
Is there a way to make the listGrid atomatically resize with resizing of the window ?
Is there a way to make the fields of the listGrid always fit the size of listGrid which always fit the width of its parent ?

Is that possible to have this result : http://jsfiddle.net/lnplnp/kJLGd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've tried `listGridField.setWidth("100%");`

So the answer is :

```
ListGridField[] listGridFields = listGrid.getFields();
for (ListGridField listGridField : listGridFields) {
  listGridField.setWidth("100%");
}
listGrid.getField("FIELDNAME").setWidth(30);
```

Assigned a fix width to at least one field, respond to my expectation.

*It work in most of case but sometime this method does not work correctly. I cannot describe the exact situation. I will edit this response if I found what make it does not work.*

Answer (score 1):

```
listGrid.setWidth("100%");
```

Have you tried this? If it doesn't fill the window check for a parent constraint.

Comment: I've got this : "listGrid.setWidth100();" Is that correct ? And same that "setWidth("100%")" I think.

Comment: Okay you've edited your answer now, setWidth100 is the same according to the API. In that case, the listGrid is most likely being constrained by a parent widget/element. When I'm in this situation, I find the Chrome debugging utilities helpful, it can help you quickly locate a element with a fixed width. Press 12 to inspect the DOM

Comment: In fact, I want that the fields width follow the resizing of the window . It appear that listGrid'width fit but not its fields width.

Comment: Perhaps you need [listGrid.setAutoFitData()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#setAutoFitData(com.smartgwt.client.types.Autofit))